# Webpack cannot compile file that uses "export * as something"

Tags: webpack, cypress, nrwl-nx

I’m trying to run `e2e` tests for a React app using Cypress and NX.

When I run `nx run dashboard-e2e:e2e` (which uses cypress) I get the following webpack compilation error:

```
Error: Webpack Compilation Error
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:9)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ../../../../Library/Caches/Cypress/11.2.0/Cypress.app/Contents/Resources/app/packages/server/node_modules/ts-loader/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
> export * as dsls from './dsls';
| export { default as apps } from './apps';
|
```

It seems to me that the problem is related to the use of `export *`. When I manually export the individual modules from `dsls` one by one the problem goes away. Also, please note that the `dsls` module exports json files actually and not typical node modules.

I am not sure how to debug this issue or whether is a webpack, cypress or Nx issue. It looks like a webpack config issue but I am not sure.

Can someone please help me?

I tried to debug it by narrowing down the error. It seems that the offending syntax is the `export *`. I have also checked the exported json modules and they are validated correctly so it's not a json syntax issue.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue and also found that the only workaround is to remove any `export *` syntax.